# How to shorten the text appearing on tradingview chart for this pine-script indicator?

Tags: pine-script

This text appears on my tradingview chart for a moving average indicator.

[image]

The text is taking up too much space. I want to shorten it to something that looks like this;

`MA EMA10,21,50,200 177979.52 18011.72 18001.40 17678.94`

Here's the code for the pine-script indicator.

```
//@version=5
indicator("EMA", shorttitle="MA", overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

ma(source, length, type) =>
    type == "SMA" ? ta.sma(source, length) :
     type == "EMA" ? ta.ema(source, length) :
     type == "SMMA (RMA)" ? ta.rma(source, length) :
     type == "WMA" ? ta.wma(source, length) :
     type == "VWMA" ? ta.vwma(source, length) :
     na

show_ma1   = input(true, "MA №1", inline="MA #1")
ma1_type   = input.string("EMA", ""     , inline="MA #1", options=["SMA", "EMA", "SMMA (RMA)", "WMA", "VWMA"])
ma1_source = input(close, "", inline="MA #1")
ma1_length = input.int(10, "", inline="MA #1", minval=1)
ma1_color  = input(#B2B5BE, "", inline="MA #1")  //silver colour
ma1 = ma(ma1_source, ma1_length, ma1_type)
plot(show_ma1 ? ma1 : na, color = ma1_color, title="MA №1")

show_ma2   = input(true, "MA №2", inline="MA #2")
ma2_type   = input.string("EMA"  , ""     , inline="MA #2", options=["SMA", "EMA", "SMMA (RMA)", "WMA", "VWMA"])
ma2_source = input(close, ""     , inline="MA #2")
ma2_length = input.int(21, ""     , inline="MA #2", minval=1)
ma2_color  = input(#FFEB3B, ""     , inline="MA #2")  //yellow colour
ma2 = ma(ma2_source, ma2_length, ma2_type)
plot(show_ma2 ? ma2 : na, color = ma2_color, title="MA №2")

show_ma3   = input(true, "MA №3", inline="MA #3")
ma3_type   = input.string("EMA"  , ""     , inline="MA #3", options=["SMA", "EMA", "SMMA (RMA)", "WMA", "VWMA"])
ma3_source = input(close, ""     , inline="MA #3")
ma3_length = input.int(50, ""     , inline="MA #3", minval=1)
ma3_color  = input(#FF7F00, ""     , inline="MA #3")  //orange
ma3 = ma(ma3_source, ma3_length, ma3_type)
plot(show_ma3 ? ma3 : na, color = ma3_color, title="MA №3")

show_ma4   = input(true, "MA №4", inline="MA #4")
ma4_type   = input.string("EMA"  , ""     , inline="MA #4", options=["SMA", "EMA", "SMMA (RMA)", "WMA", "VWMA"])
ma4_source = input(close, ""     , inline="MA #4")
ma4_length = input.int(200, ""     , inline="MA #4", minval=1)
ma4_color  = input(#00FF00, ""     , inline="MA #4")  //lime
ma4 = ma(ma4_source, ma4_length, ma4_type)
plot(show_ma4 ? ma4 : na, color = ma4_color, title="MA №4")
```

I am using pine-script v5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question. This code will shorten the text, although not exactly to what the question wants. But it is good enough.

```
//@version=5
indicator("EMA", shorttitle="EMA", overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

ma(source, length, type) =>
    type == "SMA" ? ta.sma(source, length) :
     type == "EMA" ? ta.ema(source, length) :
     type == "SMMA (RMA)" ? ta.rma(source, length) :
     type == "WMA" ? ta.wma(source, length) :
     type == "VWMA" ? ta.vwma(source, length) :
     na

show_ma1   = input(true, "MA №1", inline="MA #1")
//ma1_type   = input.string("EMA", ""     , inline="MA #1", options=["SMA", "EMA", "SMMA (RMA)", "WMA", "VWMA"])
//ma1_source = input(close, "", inline="MA #1")
ma1_length = input.int(10, "", inline="MA #1", minval=1)
ma1_color  = input(#B2B5BE, "", inline="MA #1")  //silver colour
//ma1 = ma(ma1_source, ma1_length, ma1_type)
ma1 = ma(close, ma1_length, "EMA")
plot(show_ma1 ? ma1 : na, color = ma1_color, title="MA №1")

show_ma2   = input(true, "MA №2", inline="MA #2")
//ma2_type   = input.string("EMA"  , ""     , inline="MA #2", options=["SMA", "EMA", "SMMA (RMA)", "WMA", "VWMA"])
//ma2_source = input(close, ""     , inline="MA #2")
ma2_length = input.int(21, ""     , inline="MA #2", minval=1)
ma2_color  = input(#FFEB3B, ""     , inline="MA #2")  //yellow colour
//ma2 = ma(ma2_source, ma2_length, ma2_type)
ma2 = ma(close, ma2_length, "EMA")
plot(show_ma2 ? ma2 : na, color = ma2_color, title="MA №2")

show_ma3   = input(true, "MA №3", inline="MA #3")
//ma3_type   = input.string("EMA"  , ""     , inline="MA #3", options=["SMA", "EMA", "SMMA (RMA)", "WMA", "VWMA"])
//ma3_source = input(close, ""     , inline="MA #3")
ma3_length = input.int(50, ""     , inline="MA #3", minval=1)
ma3_color  = input(#FF7F00, ""     , inline="MA #3")  //orange
//ma3 = ma(ma3_source, ma3_length, ma3_type)
ma3 = ma(close, ma3_length, "EMA")
plot(show_ma3 ? ma3 : na, color = ma3_color, title="MA №3")

show_ma4   = input(true, "MA №4", inline="MA #4")
//ma4_type   = input.string("EMA"  , ""     , inline="MA #4", options=["SMA", "EMA", "SMMA (RMA)", "WMA", "VWMA"])
//ma4_source = input(close, ""     , inline="MA #4")
ma4_length = input.int(200, ""     , inline="MA #4", minval=1)
ma4_color  = input(#00FF00, ""     , inline="MA #4")  //lime
//ma4 = ma(ma4_source, ma4_length, ma4_type)
ma4 = ma(close, ma4_length, "EMA")
plot(show_ma4 ? ma4 : na, color = ma4_

color, title="MA №4")
```